# intento subir imagenes a firebase usando el paquete react-firebase-file-uploader y recibo este error TypeError: storageRef.child is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firestore, firebase-storage

intento subir imagenes a un bucket de firebase y estoy teniendo este problema esta es mi configuracion de firebase: error firebase.storage.ref is not a function, intente cambiando la configuracion sin la clase y aun asi me sigue dando el mismo error. si alguien puede ayudarme por favor, ya no se que hacer. actualice el codigo firebase.config.js a este

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

import firebaseConfig from "./config";


class Firestore {
  constructor() {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    this.db = getFirestore(app);
    this.storage = getStorage(app);
  }

  getRef(filesRef) {
    return ref(this.storage, filesRef);
  }
}

const firebase = new Firestore();
export default firebase;
```

aca mi componente completo donde intento subir la imagen: importe react-firebase-file-uploader, pero en este caso no utilizo class components, sino hooks:no se la razon del error, hay otra manera de hacer, que error estoy cometiendo, ya he intentado cambiando la configuracion de firebase.js

```
    import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { FirebaseContext } from "../../firebase";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import FileUploader from "react-firebase-file-uploader";



const NuevoPlatillo = () => {
  //Context con las operaciones de firebase
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);
  console.log(firebase);

  //Hook para redireccionar
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  //validacion formularios
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      nombre: "",
      precio: "",
      descripcion: "",
      // imagen: "",
      categoria: "",
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      nombre: Yup.string()
        .min(4, "El nombre minimo debe tener 4 caracteres")
        .required("El nombre es requerido"),
      precio: Yup.number()
        .min(3, "El precio minimo debe tener 3 caracteres")
        .required("El precio es requerido"),
      descripcion: Yup.string()
        .min(10, "La descripcion minimo debe tener 10 caracteres")
        .required("La descripcion es requerida"),
      // imagen: Yup.string().required("La imagen es requerida"),
      categoria: Yup.string().required("La categoria es requerida"),
    }),
    onSubmit: async (articulos) => {
      try {
        articulos.existencia = true;

        const docREf = await addDoc(collection(db, "productos"), articulos);
        console.log("Datos enviados exitosamente", docREf.id);

        navigate("/menu");
        // alert(JSON.stringify(articulos, null, 2));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-light mb-4">Agregar Articulo</h1>

      <div className="flex justify-center mt-10">
        <div className="w-full max-w-3xl ">
          <form action="" onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="nombre"
                className="block text-sm font-bold text-gray-700 mb-2"
              >
                Nombre
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="nombre"
                id="nombre"
                placeholder="Nombre Platillo"
                value={formik.values.nombre}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray-500 leading-tight focus:outline focus:shadow-outline"
              />
            </div>
            {formik.touched.nombre && formik.errors.nombre ? (
              <div
                className="bg-red-100 border-l-4 border-red-500 text-red-700 p-4 mb-5"
                role="alert"
              >
                <p>{formik.errors.nombre}</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}

            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="precio"
                className="block text-sm font-bold text-gray-700 mb-2"
              >
                Precio
              </label>
              <input
                type="number"
                name="precio"
                id="precio"
                placeholder="$2.000"
                min={0}
                value={formik.values.precio}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray leading-tight focus:outline focus:shadow-outline"
              />
            </div>

            {formik.touched.precio && formik.errors.precio ? (
              <div
                className="bg-red-100 border-l-4 border-red-500 text-red-700 p-4 mb-5"
                role="alert"
              >
                <p>{formik.errors.precio}</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}

            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="precio"
                className="block text-sm font-bold text-gray-700 mb-2"
              >
                Categoria
              </label>
              <select
                id="categoria"
                name="categoria"
                value={formik.values.categoria}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray leading-tight focus:outline focus:shadow-outline"
              >
                <option value="">--Seleccione--</option>
                <option value="desayuno">Desayuno</option>
                <option value="comida">Comida</option>
                <option value="cena">Cena</option>
                <option value="bebidas">Bebidas</option>
                <option value="postres">Postres</option>
                <option value="ensalada">Ensalada</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            {formik.touched.categoria && formik.errors.categoria ? (
              <div
                className="bg-red-100 border-l-4 border-red-500 text-red-700 p-4 mb-5"
                role="alert"
              >
                <p>{formik.errors.categoria}</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}

            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="imagen"
                className="block text-sm font-bold text-gray mb-2"
              >
                Imagen
              </label>
              <FileUploader
                accept="image/*"
                name="imagen"
                randomizeFilename
                storageRef={firebase.storage.getRef("prductos")}
                // onUploadStart={this.handleUploadStart}
                // onUploadError={this.handleUploadError}
                // onUploadSuccess={this.handleUploadSuccess}
                // onProgress={this.handleProgress}
                // className="category-file-uploader"
              />
            </div>
            {formik.touched.imagen && formik.errors.imagen ? (
              <div
                className="bg-red-100 border-l-4 border-red-500 text-red-700 p-4 mb-5"
                role="alert"
              >
                <p>{formik.errors.imagen}</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}

            <div className="mb-4">
              <label
                htmlFor="descripcion"
                className="block text-sm font-bold text-gray mb-2"
              >
                Descripción
              </label>
              <textarea
                name="descripcion"
                id="descripcion"
                placeholder="Descripción del Platillo"
                value={formik.values.descripcion}
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-3 px-3 text-gray leading-tight focus:outline focus:shadow-outline h-40"
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            {formik.touched.descripcion && formik.errors.descripcion ? (
              <div
                className="bg-red-100 border-l-4 border-red-500 text-red-700 p-4 mb-5"
                role="alert"
              >
                <p>{formik.errors.descripcion}</p>
              </div>
            ) : null}

            <input
              type="submit"
              className="bg-red-800 hover:bg-red-900 w-full mt-5 p-2 text-white font-bold rounded-lg"
            />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NuevoPlatillo;
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, `ref` ya no es una función de `firebase.storage`, fue separada y ahora debes importarla aparte (Firebase v9), igual que `getStorage` Como lo indican en la documentación oficial de Firebase:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference?hl=es#create_a_reference

A fin de subir o descargar archivos, borrar archivos, obtener o actualizar metadatos, debes crear una referencia al archivo con el que deseas trabajar. Se puede decir que una referencia es un indicador que apunta a un archivo en la nube. Las referencias son livianas, por lo que puedes crear todas las que necesites, y también son reutilizables para múltiples operaciones.

(A continuación una explicación del equipo de Firebase (Obtenida del enlace de arriba). Si quieres saltar a cómo se vería tu código con la solución implementada, está más abajo, luego del texto resaltado en negritas.)

Para crear una referencia, obtén una instancia del servicio de `Storage` mediante `getStorage()` y, luego, llama a `ref()` con el servicio como argumento. Esta referencia apunta a la raíz del bucket de Cloud Storage.

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

// Obtén una referencia al servicio de almacenamiento, que se utiliza para crear referencias en su depósito de almacenamiento:
const storage = getStorage();

// Crear una referencia de almacenamiento desde nuestro (Firebase cloud storage) servicio de almacenamiento
const storageRef = ref(storage);
```

Puedes crear una referencia a una ubicación de un nivel inferior del árbol, como `'images/space.jpg'`, pasando esta ruta de acceso como un segundo argumento cuando llamas a `ref()`.

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

// Crea una referencia secundaria
const imagesRef = ref(storage, 'images');
// imagesRef now points to 'images'

// Las referencias secundarias también pueden tomar rutas delimitadas por '/'
const spaceRef = ref(storage, 'images/space.jpg');
// spaceRef ahora apunta a "images/space.jpg"
// imagesRef todavía apunta a "imágenes"
```

**En tu caso, si quieres acceder a estas funcionalidades desde la instancia de la clase que definiste como `Firestore` en tu código:**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";


const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
   authDomain: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
   projectId: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
   storageBucket: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
   messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
   appId: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
   measurementId: import.meta.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
 };

class Firestore {
  constructor() {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    this.db = getFirestore(app);
    this.storage = getStorage(app);
  }

  getRef(filesRef) {
    return ref(this.storage, filesRef);
  }
}


const firebase = new Firestore();
export default firebase;
```

Y en tu otro archivo:

```
{/* Resto de tu código... */}

<FileUploader
  accept="image/*"
  name="avatar"
  randomizeFilename
  storageRef={firebase.storage.getRef("prductos")}

{/* Resto de tu código... */}
```

Espero que mi respuesta te ayude y puedas continuar con tu proyecto!

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, realizo tus pasos y ahora me sale este error " Uncaught TypeError: firebase.storage.getRef is not a function"

Comment: he estado cambiando codigo y ahora me lanza lo siguiente "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: storageRef.child is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Discúlpame por el error, copié tu código con la intención de pegarlo con la corrección pero por alguna razón no lo actualicé. He editado mi respuesta anterior con la corrección. Te la dejo resumida por acá:

La forma de llamar el método (usando la instancia de tu clase `Firestore` actuializada) `getRef` es `firebase.getRef`:

```
const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);

{/* Resto de tu código... */}

storageRef=firebase.getRef("productos")

{/* Resto de tu código... */}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo editar tu otra respuesta y añadir la información necesaria ahí. El problema de escribir dos respuestas es que la conversación puede bifurcarse. Si escribes dos respuestas quizás alguna de las dos no sea autocontenida y completa.

Comment: Si sos el mismo usuario que redactó la otra respuesta, solicitá combinar tus perfiles de usuario en _Problema de Cuenta_ > _Necesito combinar perfiles de usuario_ [aquí](/contact).

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte @kevinAriza, sin embargo no pude hacerlo de la forma que me suministraste. estuve leyendo y al parecer react-firebase-file-uploader no tiene una version compatible con firebase v9